# Is the edit-mode tag needed?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently several questions were tagged [edit-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit-mode). It has no description and has very few answers associated with it (probably because the tag itself appeared not so long ago).

With this logic, there would be needed tags 'object-mode', 'weight-mode' etc. but wouldn't that be overtagging ? I don't see what becomes clearer with this tag; it could be better to tag some of the adjacent questions as 'editing' and add several others fitting the situation.
Or probably it should be used *only* for troubleshooting questions with scripting solutions where mentioning interaction mode is important.

So is this tag really needed ? Does it make a post in any way better understandable / searchable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, generally these should fall under the broader [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing) or [mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesh) sometimes which is more meta. I've made it a synonym to [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing). As we also have tags such as [weight-painting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-painting) and [texture-painting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-painting) we really don't need tags for the specific interaction modes.

Comment: Feel free to start a discussion on this here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And another question..I wanted to make sure there aren't cases when mentioning interaction mode could be important. E.g. [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52501/mode-problem-after-reopening-blend-file), where this is what is discussed; this fits under python and editing though.

Comment: That shifts more to `python` and is tagged properly IMO. Maybe a tag for `interaction-mode` specifically could come in handy. We do tag cleanups every now and then so will keep and eye on it, but we have the big useful general ones now that work.

Comment: I feel as if it would be good for questions about the way Edit mode works or perhaps a bug inside it. Although I can't see new people or even some others using it at the right times. (My opinion, not a solution)